# WordPress Permalink Changed, Can't Access Pages

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2

On the front end of my WordPress 3.5.2 site, I have three buttons: Home, Blog and Sample Page. When my Permalink Settings are set to `Default`, I can access these three pages:

```
Home: http://ec2-xx-xxx-x-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

Blog: http://ec2-xx-xxx-x-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/?page_id=13

Sample Page:
http://ec2-xx-xxx-x-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/?page_id=2
```

**However, when I changed my Permalink Settings to `Post name`, and refreshed the browser, I cannot access the Blog page and Sample page.** I get the following errors:

```
Blog: http://ec2-xx-xxx-x-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/blog 
Not Found
The requested URL /blog/ was not found on this server.

Sample Page:
http://ec2-xx-xxx-x-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/sample-page/ 
Not Found
The requested URL /sample-page/ was not found on this server.
```

In WordPress's `Settings -> Permalink Settings`, I also get this message:

`If your .htaccess file were writable, we could do this automatically, but it isn’t so these are the mod_rewrite rules you should have in your .htaccess file. Click in the field and press CTRL + a to select all.`

When I checked my permissions for the .htaccess file, I got 644, so I changed it to 666 and the message disappeared (I changed it back to 644)

```
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xxx-xxx-xx html]$ ls -l .htaccess
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 258 Jul 25 21:49 .htaccess 
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xxx-xxx-xx html]$ sudo chmod 666 .htaccess
```

I can still access my home page after changing the permalink settings to `Post name`. I'm not sure if this has anything to do with my problem but I installed my WordPress site in a subdirectory (xxx) on my Amazon EC2 micro instance and I changed WP's General Settings as follows:

```
WordPress Address (URL): http://ec2-xx-xxx-x-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/xxx

Site Address (URL): http://ec2-xx-xxx-x-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this by googling "permalinks htaccess amazon ec2", it might help: http://guiem.info/permalinks-on-wordpress-amazon-ec2/

Comment: +1 Thank you for your reply. I followed the instructions in the link you provide and restarted httpd. Unfortunately, it did not work.

Comment: +1 Thank you so much phil. I reread the instructions and apparently I missed the second step. It is working now!

Comment: Don't forget to reset the httpd: service httpd restart

Answer (score 3):

Make a .htaccess file at the root of your Wordpress installation. Then add the following -

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

If you want Wordpress to do it automatically, then change the file permission to 777 using `chmod`.