# Moved site to local give "localhost url not found" error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, localhost

I have a problem with my Wordpress website since I moved it to local. It does not work anymore.

Home page (`localhost`) is ok, but all other pages, for example "shop" (`localhost/shop`), gives me this error:

> xampp : Object not found
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server

The live site (aloocake.com and aloocake.com/shop) works

I use these code also:

```
define('FORCE_SSL', false);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost/wp');
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://localhost/wp' );
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You change in the database also your site URL and other parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress Permalink Changed, Can't Access Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767954/wordpress-permalink-changed-cant-access-pages)

Comment: @Subhash Patel I can't understand what do you mean

Comment: @Hassan are you change URL in your local database table wp_options, wp_posts etc

Comment: @Subhash Patel yeah I updated all of them but it is not working

Comment: @Hassan goto settings and update permalinks. It's clear that your site is at `localhost/wp` so shop page on localhost will throw error. It should be `localhost/wp/shop`

Comment: @TOH19 thanks for your help I've solved my problem

Comment: @shyammakwana.me thanks it works

Comment: @Hassan welcome to the Community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very old bug in Wordpress that makes permalinks using the page names not working after a migration to another server although the links have been changed correctly in the database. Usually it helps if you go to the WP backend, select the "Permalinks" page, change the setting to anything else, save it, then change it back and save again. Often it's even enough just to open the Permalinks page and click "save changes" there.

Comment: **For info:** It's is called "Flush WordPress rewrite rules" and it can be done just **clicking once on "Save changes" button** (located in WordPress Settings > Permalinks page)